# Problem with restful route in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in routes.rb:

```
  resource :account, :controller => "accounts"
  resources :accounts
```

this redirect is in a controller:

```
  redirect_to account_url
```

and when this redirect is called, I get the following error:

Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"accounts"}

The following are displayed when running *rake routes*:

...
...
accounts DELETE /accounts(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"accounts"}
...
...
account DELETE /accounts/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"accounts"}
...
...

So it seems to me that I've got the {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"accounts"} covered -> according to *rake routes* anyways. Anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's that first route's intention? It should be enough with the second one to map HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically.

Comment: being new to rails, I was following a tutorial (written pre-Rails 3) on setting up Authlogic. I 'converted' the defined routes as I thought they should be, going from rails 2 to 3... and ended up with the two that I've shown above. Interestingly, I thought the second defined route should be enough to do the trick, so I tried removing the first one, but was still running into the problem. Since posting, I tried switching the order of the two defined routes, and that 'fixed' the problem.